# How do I stop the "Are you sure you want to open it?" dialog box from displaying when I open an app?

Tags: macos, mac

Every time I open the "Amazon MP3 Downloader" app (by downloading a new MP3 from Amazon.com in Safari) I get this dialog box:
[image]

I'm used to seeing this the first time after I open a new app I've downloaded, but usually I don't see the dialog box after the first time I press the "Open" button.

Is there a setting somewhere I can use to indicate that yes, I am sure I want to open "Amazon MP3 Downloader" without this dialog box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to do this manually on a file (or files) you can run the following command to remove the Quarantine flag:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /PATH/TO/FILE(S)
```

So in your case since the quarantine flag is not being removed you will want to run the command with `sudo` as the primary cause for the flag not being removed after hitting "Open" is because you don't have permissions to do so.

Comment: The quarantine flag does seem to be removed for other applications I've downloaded since.  Are the permissions set separately for each app?

Comment: How do I give myself permission to remove quarantine flags?

Comment: @Daryl Spitzer: Most likely it's just because of Amazon's app only. Using `sudo` in front of that command will allow you to do the command as if you were root and make sure it takes effect. If it fails to work, change `-d` to `-dr` and run it with sudo in case there is another program inside with the flag.

Comment: xattr worked (with the -d option) but I did need to use sudo

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called `com.apple.DownloadAssessment.plist` under `Library/Preferences` with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>LSRiskCategoryNeutral</key>
    <dict>
      <key>LSRiskCategoryContentTypes</key>
      <array>
        <string>public.item</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Then log out and then log back in.

Instructions for Snow Leopard are [a bit different](http://pseudogreen.org/blog/yes_snow_leopard_i_want_to_open_it_already.html).

Comment: Will this turn off the alert message when downloading other (new) applications?

Comment: @Daryl: Yes. Otherwise you can use **Chealion**'s solution to manually remove the quarantine flag.

Answer (score 3):

Deeper would be a good choice but I would suggest you to use **[OnyX](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/onyx.html)**

OnyX provides a few more features than Deeper, allowing you to verify the Startup Disk and the structure of its System files and to delete caches.
[image]

Comment: Good information, but I just want to turn off the alert for the one particular app.

Answer (score 1):

if you use [Deeper](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/deeper.html) you can mark it in General tab.

[image]

Comment: Good information, but I just want to turn off the alert for the one particular app.