# Disable "...application downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?" on certain file types?

Tags: settings

Is it possible to modify which files Apple's quarantine warning pops up on?  Specifically I download hundreds of PHP files (web developer) and I'm tired of seeing "...is a script application downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?"  I don't mind the warning on most downloads, but don't want warnings on scripts I'm opening to edit.

FYI, Quarantine can be completly disabled with:
    defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO
and can be removed from existing files with:
    xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine ~/*foldername*

Answer (score 3):

If you download files from the internet into the `~/Downloads` folder, you could assign a folder action to `~/Downloads` via Automator:

Open Automator
Create a new Folder Action

As the action, drag over "Run Shell Script"

Assign the following shell script:

```
    for f in "$@"
    do
        test "$f" == *\.php && xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine $f
    done
```

Comment: Hmm this might work, but the problem isn't files going to /Downloads, it's all my Git repos and sites.  I could set it up to run on those folders recursively I suppose.  /Downloads is actually the one places I'd like to it run.

Answer (score 2):

Building from @Daniel's answer, you could do this from a shell:

```
find /path/to/your/app -name '*.php' -exec xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine {} \;
```